# css min-margin for vertical margins

Tags: html, css, margin

What needs to change in this code so that:
1) The left column (red) is at least 200px wide, and at most 20% wide
2) The "main" column (black) is at lease 400px wide, and at most 80% wide
3) The columns always remain horizontally adjacent, with the "main" column never wrapping to a new line?

Note: This may appear to be a duplicate of other "min-margin" type css questions here, but I've been through a few to no avail, such as this one: [Using a percentage margin in CSS but want a minimum margin in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350645/using-a-percentage-margin-in-css-but-want-a-minimum-margin-in-pixels)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Margin Test</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: green;
        }
        #left-column {
            display: table-cell;
            min-width: 200px;
            width: 20%;
            background-color: red;
            float: left;
        }
        #main-column {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 80%;
            background-color: black;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left-column">
            left
        </div>
        <div id="main-column">
            main
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your logic is flawed. What if the 100% width of the container is less than 600px wide (i.e. the sum of the two widths)? Both elements cannot be a maximum of 80% wide each without wrapping...

Comment: @BenM Then a horizontal scroll bar will appear at the bottom of the browser window

Comment: @BuddhistBeast no, because if you resize the output window, they wrap.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast no. The left sidebar now has less width than the minimum 200px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/p2mdj/

Is that what you want? I removed the...

```
float: left;
```

because table-cells automatically figure that out and added a

```
min-width: 400px
```

to your main div.

It's now basically a standard table with a minimum width for each cell specified. Tables will pretty much never wrap their cells unless you do some weird stuff (like put floats on them :P)

Comment: Will accept in 7 minutes when available. This solved the problem. Was that jsfiddle link meant to link to a specific fiddle? Or you're saying I should use that in future when asking questions?

Comment: Uhh I updated that link, it's now to a specific fiddle